# My Linear Regression Model Mean Absolute Error(MAE) is 0.29 and R2 0.20 , Is this a acceptable Model?

Tags: machine-learning, python, regression, linear-regression, rmse

My Linear Regression Model Mean Absolute Error(MAE) is 0.29 and R2 0.20 , Is this a acceptable Model ?

How can increase the r2 score ?

[image]

Comment: Only you can decide that, is a MAE of 0.29 acceptable to you?

Comment: is this model is good or bad ?

Comment: Impossible to fully answer this question without context regarding the problem you are trying to solve. Even if you use R square and MAE by itself, these numbers can vary by subject matter.

Answer (score 2):

[Under the usual conditions (that you probably satisfy), $R^2$ can be interpreted as the proportion of variance in $y$ explained by your model.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/555145/ridge-regression-for-multicollinearity-and-outliers/555163#555163) This means that your model explains $20\%$ of the variance in $y$.

Mean absolute error is the mean amount by which your model predictions miss the observed values. This means that, on average, your model misses by $0.29$.

It’s up to you to put those numbers in context. These metrics aren’t equivalent to grades in school where being over $R^2=0.90$ is an $A$-grade and scoring $R^2=0.2$ is an $F$-grade. There are situations where the low $R^2$ (or high MAE) could be fantastic for your task, and there are situations where the high $R^2$ (or low MAE) could indicate rather pedestrian performance.

Comment: I have addressed your first question about deciding if your performance metrics indicate an acceptable model. Your second question about increasing the $R^2$ score is equivalent to asking how to do machine learning, statistical modeling, and predictive analytics, so that question is much too broad for this Stack or any other.